# action-state not accept evaluate tags Spring Web Flow 2.3

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow-2

Eclipse marks this error

*cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'action-state'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":on-end, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":output, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":exception-handler, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":bean-import}' is expected.*

on this flow code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd" 
abstract="true">


<global-transitions>
    <transition on="logIn" to ="login" />
    <transition on="signup" to="signup"/>
    <transition on="logOut" to="logout"/>
</global-transitions>

<action-state id="logout">
    <evaluate expression="login.logout(currentUser)" />
    <transition on="successLogout" to="main" />
    <transition on="failLogout" to="error" />
</action-state>
```

I only find action-state samples and everyone are writting like my code and people use the same XSD. Either, I have read XSD file and on action-state section tag evaluate is missing. Why eclipse marks this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Now, I have edited because I copied incorrect code, sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there has to be an order in which the elements are defined. Try defining the `action-state` before the `global-transitions`. If you hover your mouse pointer over the "flow" xml definition in your xml file this info appears (among others):

```
Content Model : (attribute*, secured?, persistence-context?, var*, input*, on-start?, (action-state | view-state | decision-state | subflow-state | end-state)*, global-transitions?, on-end?, output*, exception-handler*, bean-import*)
```

So, there is a [strict sequence](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_sequence.asp).

Comment: And all the elements in the "Content Model" above are defined in a `xsd:sequence`.

Comment: Cheers! The problem is fixed, and your link helped me because I was a little bit of confused reading any XSD files :)

Comment: Cool :-). Sometimes is useful to go over the xsd and see what is expected from an xml.